# How to use SBT to create an IDEA plugin project?

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, sbt

We can use IntelliJ-IDEA to import an normal SBT project easily, but I'm trying to write an IDEA plugin project with Scala, and I want to use SBT to manage it(the dependencies).

But now I don't know how to do it, and not sure if it's possible, so I have to use IDEA to create an IDEA plugin project manually, and commit the `.idea/*` files to git, which is not good.

Is it possible to use SBT to create an IDEA plugin project?

Comment: Look at the Scala plugin sources https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the exact code would look. But the play framework does something like what you want. They let you create an IDEA project with

```
[My first application] $ idea
```

So you can .gitignore the .idea/* folder and every developer can easily create their own IDEA project if they want to use an IDE.

Their documentation describes how you use it, so it should be easy enough to find the code that actually generates the project: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/IDE

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but IDEA plugin project is a little bit different from normal Scala project, it seems need some special config to make it a "plugin" project, so I can launch the plugin in a new sandbox IDEA directly.

Comment: Can you track if the "special config" changes over time? If not you just can take an archive of a snapshot of the .idea folder and then just export it when the developer wants to create idea project files?